# Inconsistent Results for New Users Count in Elasticsearch Dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm encountering an issue with Elasticsearch version "8.4.1" in a dashboard that displays current active users, new users, and the total number of messages.
The data is tracked for the past two months, from May to August.

The problem lies in the inconsistency of the new users count. For instance, in July, the count was `1902`, but upon retesting yesterday, it's showing `1903`. The same inconsistency is observed in August, where the count was `3894`, but now it's `3899`.

The other counts are consistent(total messages, active users).
I'm using the same logic to retrieve active users count, with the only difference being the field used for the date range. I use `created_date` for new users and `dateTime` for active users. Both fields are of the same type:

```
"created_date": {
"type": "date_nanos",
"store": true,
"format": "date_optional_time" }
```

Below is the Java code snippet I'm using to fetch the new users count:

```
private Terms getNewUsersTerms(Integer botId, String from, String to) {
try {
    RestHighLevelClient client = getElasticClient(botId);

    AggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("uniqueIds").field("currentState.user.id").size(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("currentState.created_date").gte("2023-08-01").lte("2023-08-31"));

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
        .aggregation(aggregationBuilder)
        .query(queryBuilder).size(0);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(botId + INDEX_POSTFIX)
        .source(searchSourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return searchResponse.getAggregations().get("uniqueIds");
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
}}
```

I'm seeking guidance on what might be missing in my approach and what steps I can take to identify and resolve this inconsistency issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a documented behaviour from elasticsearch : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#terms-agg-doc-count-error

Comment: Do you mind sharing the raw result of the aggregation query with two different counts?